# Access/extract R help from non-R script (e.g. Python)

Tags: python, r

I found a number of functions here on stackoverflow that extract the html code of help files from within R but I would like to access the help files from an external script (Python). How can I get the actual html code of the help file from outside of R?

Here are possible solutions:

1. Use console call to R from Python or other language such as this one
   R --slave -e 'library(MASS); help(survey)' > survey.txt
   The problem with this approach is that I often don't know in which package a specific function is. So this approach does not really work. Or are there work arounds?
2. Extract all help files from R and save them in a database, which can be accessed from an external script. Shouldn't be to hard but it's kind of annoying also because this help database has to be updated by rerunning the script.
3. Access R's help database directly but I have no idea about the structure etc!?

Any ideas and possible solutions?

Edit: I also thought about the `helpr` package but wasn't able to try it with R 2.15 because of this bug
https://github.com/hadley/helpr/issues/27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to compile R from its sources, then directly accessing the help files (your option 3) seems like it may be the cleanest and easiest approach.

The various html help files that come with an R binary distribution are stored in:

```
R_HOME/doc/html/                 # CHANGES, NEWS, other miscellany
R_HOME/doc/manual/               # An Intro to R, R Language Definition, etc.
R_HOME/library/<pkg-name>/html/  # help files for packages
```

Unfortunately for your purposes, (as explained in [section 2.2 of R-admin](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Help-options)), "by default, HTML help pages are created when needed rather than being built at install time".  At least for Windows (and, it appears, for Mac) the standard R binaries available from CRAN were built with these default settings.

If you *are* willing/able to compile R from its sources, you can set an optional flag/directive telling R to create those static HTML help pages. On UNIX (and, I'd guess Mac OS X) operating systems, do this by setting the configure option `--enable-prebuilt-html`. On Windows, set `BUILD_HTML = YES` in either "MkRules.dist" or "MkRules.local" prior to running `make all recommended`.

Comment: But the problem is that they do not contain the actual html files...
For example, format should be here but is not `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/base/html/format.html`. As far as I understand the R help system (and my understanding is very limited), the help files are generated from some database.

Comment: OK, yes. I misspoke above. You'll need an installation of R for which the static help files have been created, and they are not in the default Windows binary. If you compile the source yourself, you can change the defaults, with the flag `--enable-prebuilt-html` (on UNIX systems), or by setting `BUILD_HTML = YES` in `MkRules.dist` on Windows. See the R-admin manual for more info, including what to do on Macs. (Also, I'll do a more complete edit of the post above, as soon as I get a chance.)

Comment: ok, great. Thanks. I guess there is no way to do that once R installed. The compiling solution is going to work for myself but I might distribute the script and hurdle might be to big for a lot of users.